# forcibly rerun publish in meteor not working even with Reactive-var

Tags: meteor

I am using Reactive-var, trying to republish the entire collection. I am using latest ***Meteor 1.5***. Everything works fine except that the already solved question still appears in the list even though I have exempted them from publishing.

> In Below server, once client submits answer to a question, a new question data must be re-published except all correctly answered questions. That is what is not happening here. But when I refresh the page, things work! But I need this in real time manner, without refreshing page.

**SERVER CODE**

```
Meteor.publish('Question.Random', function(refreshValue){
    var clientQuestions = [];
    var clientCorrectQuestions = QuestionHistory.find({userId : this.userId, result : 1}, {_id : 0, questionId : 1});
    if(clientCorrectQuestions.count() > 0){
        //get array of correct solved questions
      clientCorrectQuestions.map( function(correctQuestion) {
          clientQuestions.push(correctQuestion.questionId);
      });
    }
    var randomskipCount = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1; 
    return Question.find({_id : { $nin: clientQuestions}});
});
```

**CLIENT CODE**

```
Template.temp1.onCreated(function(){
  this.refreshValue = new ReactiveVar(0);
  Meteor.subscribe('Question.Random', this.refreshValue.get());
});

Template.temp1.events({
  "click .myBtn": function(event, template){
      event.preventDefault();

      Meteor.call('processUserInput', function(error, response){

          if(error){
            Bert.alert("<strong>Error !", 'danger', 'fixed-top' );
          } else if(response){
            instance.refreshValue.set(Math.floor(Math.random() * 500));
          }
        });
      return false;
  }
});
```

any help would be greatly appreciated and rewarded.

Comment: I do not really understand your question. I see `refreshValue` is passed the publication function but never used. Are you trying to change the published result based on `QuestionHistory`?

Comment: I read a post somewhere to add reactive-var to the subcribe function, then change them dynamically, this will cause the subscription to refresh. But nothing happens. And YES! you are right, I am trying to change the published result based on QuestionHistory as User has already solved it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should wrap your subscription in `autorun`:

```
Template.temp1.onCreated(function(){
  this.refreshValue = new ReactiveVar(0);
  this.autorun(() => {
    Meteor.subscribe('Question.Random', this.refreshValue.get());
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I see that you are trying to do publication with aggregation. There are more than one way to do it. In this case you just need to wrap the subscribe command inside a reactive block:

```
Template.temp1.onCreated(function() {
  this.refreshValue = new ReactiveVar(0);
  this.autorun(() => {
    this.subscribe('Question.Random', this.refreshValue.get());
  });
});
```